# What does $ in Erlang shell output information mean

Tags: shell, dictionary, process, erlang, output

[shell info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fLBN.jpg)

when enter the follow Erlang shell command:

```
proc_lib:spawn(fun() -> io:format("~p~n",[process_info(self())]) end).
```

The Erlang will show the following info in the picture.

```
[{current_function,{erl_eval,do_apply,6}},
 {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,3}},
 {status,running},
 {message_queue_len,0},
 {messages,[]},
 {links,[]},
 {dictionary,[{'$ancestors',[<0.32.0>]},
              {'$initial_call',{erl_eval,'-expr/5-fun-3-',0}}]},
 {trap_exit,false},
 {error_handler,error_handler},
 {priority,normal},
 {group_leader,<0.25.0>},
 {total_heap_size,233},
 {heap_size,233},
 {stack_size,27},
 {reductions,72},
 {garbage_collection,[{min_bin_vheap_size,46422},
                      {min_heap_size,233},
                      {fullsweep_after,65535},
                      {minor_gcs,0}]},
 {suspending,[]}]
<0.34.0>
```

What does "$",6 and 5-fun-3- (In case you don't know what I'm referring to, I've uploaded a picture to illustrate)mean in the Erlang shell output info? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In Erlang, anything enclosed in single quotes, e.g. `'$ancestors'` is an `atom`.

Comment: I knew atom,I thought $ should have some special meaning.